Best way to have second read-only db connection with Spring JDBC
I'm developing on an spring boot app using Hibernate and an Postgresql db for persistence. Nothing special so far and working as intended.
Now i want to have (read-only) access to second database which is used by a different app. I only want to read some data on demand by the user. There is no need for a permanent connection to the db. It's totally fine if the db is not available. In this case the user is just not be able to fetch data from the second db.
So the requirement is more like having an external API which can be used to fetch some data if available.
I started with adding it as a second datasource. But when the db is not available the container won't start.
Beyond that, i was wondering what's the best way for situations like that where the db connection should more work like an external rest api?

Try to set:
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true

As written in the Spring Boot Reference Documentation:

By default, Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of its
script-based database initializer. This means that, if the scripts
cause exceptions, the application fails to start.



I started with adding it as a second datasource. But when the db is not available the container won't start.

I know nothing of Spring Boot & Hibernate specifically, but you should be able to isolate the call out to the read-only database in such a way that it's failure / absence should not fail the entire spring boot container (I'm assuming that's the type of container you're referring to).

Beyond that, i was wondering what's the best way for situations like
that where the db connection should more work like an external rest
api?

There are various, but no one way is best - the most suitable approach will depend on your circumstances - e.g. how much data? how often does the data change? etc.  Most patterns can be bent a little to suit your specific situation too.
As a general rule, when dealing with external data sources (stuff you don't control) you want to make sure it (meaning your code / how you talk to it) is isolated - in such a way that's easy for you to absorb unexpected changes and outages.  Have you heard of "Loose Coupling" before?  If not, do some research - it's a massively important concept.
Of interest to you:

Something like the Gateway Pattern is a good general starting point: https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html  The idea here is simply to have a wrapper.  It's where you'd handle all the connection specific stuff like handling database unavailability; you could even adding in stuff like caching.

In terms of connectivity, you can try something like exponential back-off.  Make your Gateway code "smart" in the sense that it knows when it last tried to access the database and failed; only re-try after a certain period of time.  E.g. the first time a query/connection fails, wait 5 seconds then try again; on the next error wait 30 seconds, then 5 minutes (whatever).  After 3 consecutive errors you might wait for a long time and then only re-try once an hours (whatever is appropriate).  The moment you get a successful connection you basically "reset" back to normal.  The idea here is that if the error was fleeting, you can get back to normal system behavior quickly, but if problems persist you can wait until it's more likely to have been fixed, and not do lots of wasteful processing / requests in the meantime.  I can't recall any off the top of my head but there will be other similar patterns like this.

Also consider Database-level approaches: e.g. make a database that you control; copy data from the source database to yours using database server level tools, such as replication. The data will only update when the source database is up, but at least you application code can query what it needs to from your copy of the database.


